# Is it possible to emit the numpad arrow key in Java?

Tags: java, awtrobot, jnativehook

**Background**
Operating systems (I'm on Windows 10, if it matters) have a feature called [Mouse Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys) that allow you to perform the operations of the mouse using the numpad. Press 5 to click, 8/2/4/6 to move the cursor up/down/left/right, and so on.

**The Desire**
I would like to move the cursor around when Mouse Keys is activated, programmatically, in Java. I specifically want to use keyboard events for this, as moving the mouse directly is verboten in the context I'm in.

**The Problem**
I tried using `Robot.keyPress` and `Robot.keyRelease` with keycode `KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP = 224`, but that yields the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code 
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Robot.java:350)
```

And trying it with `KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8` doesn't error out, but also doesn't make the mouse move.

I also tried [jnativehook's](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) `GlobalScreen.postNativeEvent(new NativeKeyEvent(...))`, and no amount of voodoo could get it to work either. There's no constant in `NativeKeyEvent` for the keypad up key, so that's not super surprising. When I try to send the keycode 224, the following error occurs:

```
com.github.kwhat.jnativehook.GlobalScreen postNativeEvent
WARNING: map_keyboard_event [97]: Unable to lookup scancode: 224
```

Am I asking the impossible?

Comment: Guessing this goes down to the OS level, as I'm not seeing any KB events fired. Popping over to a kb/m events testing site shows that no keyboard events fire, but mouse events do. Gonna leave the question up in case of a miracle, but this seems impossible.